# Is there a way to add specific condition to method with annotation?

Tags: java, java-8, annotations

I have a method and I want to add some condition to this method.

If condition is true then execute this method, if its not then skip this method. Like;

```
@SomeConditionAnnotation(check)
public void calculate(){
   //some calculations
}

public boolean check(){
  //return boolean
}
```

What I really try to do is;

```
public void calculate(){
    if(check()){
        //some calculations
    }
}
```

Comment: I suggest you do the second one as a) it is clearer and b) actually works.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think, you should use plain old "if-else", not annotation. So, you write

> If condition is true then execute this method, if its not then skip this method.

But it's description of `if` operator!

Here is purpose of annotations:

> Annotations, a form of metadata, provide data about a program that **is not part of the program itself**. Annotations have no direct effect on the operation of the code they annotate.
>    [link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/annotations/)

Answer (score 1):

What you describe can be done using an interceptor or decorator. You can use `CDI` (part of Java EE, but also usable standalone) or `aspectj` or `Spring AOP` or ... There exist lots of frameworks which support [aspect oriented programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming).